# Spark Csv specify new line character

Tags: apache-spark, newline, delimited, spark-csv

I am writing a data frame using spark csv library. I am using spark 1.6. I was wondering if there is a way to specify the new line character. Usually, I think it is \n.

Or if not, is there a good solution to changing the new line character?

```
view.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("delimiter", "\036").option("charset","ascii").save(location);
```

Comment: Did you get any answer for this ?

Comment: I did not, we ended up having a different solution completely so did not pursue further.